# Linq / Linqtoexcel issue selecting

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, object, linq-to-excel

I have a weird issue which I totally not understand. Maybe I'm missing something.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("products.xlsx");
//get all products with discount
var discounts = from s in excel.Worksheet() where
    s["Discount/Premium"].Cast<string>().StartsWith("-") select s;
//Select products with a YTM higher than 3
var applicable = from b in discounts where 
    b["YTM"].Cast<double>() > 3.0 select b;
MessageBox.Show(discounts.Count().ToString()); //<- returns 51
MessageBox.Show(applicable.Count().ToString()); //<- returns 14826
```

- `products.xlsx` got around `50'000` Rows/Products
- There are `51` products with discounts
- There are `14'000` products with "YTM > 3.0" - ***HOW can this be?***

To my my knowledge, I'm searching YTM products in discounts. How can I get 14'000 products from 51?!? Am I missing something?

Best regards, Julian

Comment: Maybe is the linq provider that is not applying an &&. Try calling `ToLis`t in your second query: `from b in discounts.ToList() where` to force the query to Linq to Object

Comment: thanks that works however i have no clue on why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 3rd party library that allows you to do queries over the xls ([Linq to Excel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel)). But the issue in your second query should be due how was implemented the Linq provider to query the excel document. At the time you call `ToList()`, you are bringing those rows to memory, so you are no longer using that Linq provider, you are now using Linq to Object over the 51 rows.

Usually when you compose queries as your case, the condition you are applying in your second query is treated as an `&&` by the Linq provider. I don't know why is not the case in Linq to Excel

Comment: well when i use an && I get totally unpredictable results. i think ill stay with ToList

Comment: I usually use [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) when I need to manipulate excel documents

Comment: i dont want to manipulate it, i just want to get a list of "applicable products" to interact with a website and buy products automatically ;)